# How to retrieve all records based on foreign key concept of MYSQL in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase, Here is my database I have successfully retrieved data from TopCategories and shown them on UI, Now when a user clicks on category i want to send query to firebase and want to retrieve all the records based on CategoryId. Your suggestion and help will be needful.  Thanks in Advance ! [image]

Comment: spelling of categoryID in TopCategories and ProductDetail mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I was missing

```
Query allproductQuery = ref.orderByChild(ProductDetail.categoryId)
                           .equalTo(categoryId);
```

The final code

```
Firebase ref=new Firebase(Constant.FIREBASE_URL+"/ProductDetail");
    Query allproductQuery=ref.orderByChild(ProductDetail.categoryId).equalTo(categoryId);
    allproductQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.i("success product count",dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()+"");
            tempProduct=new ProductDetail();
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                tempProduct=dataSnapshot1.getValue(ProductDetail.class);
                 mProductList.add(tempProduct);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
```

May be Helpful for someone.